# Why is my currentAccessToken always nil?

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-login, fbsdk

I am under the impression that the Facebook SDK should save my token.

I log in just fine and get the token. This is acceptable for the first time using the app. However, the SDK never saves the token. I'm forced to log in every time.

```
let currentToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()

if currentToken != nil {
    upload()
} else {
    login()
}
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? Maybe an AppDelegate.Swift function to retrieve the token?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken nil after quitting app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950937/fbsdkaccesstoken-currentaccesstoken-nil-after-quitting-app)