# Why my Facebook Share button is greyed out?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a share button with following code:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile];
FBSDKShareButton *shareButton = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] init];
shareButton.shareContent = content;
shareButton.center = CGPointMake(60, 60);
```

And I see that my share button is greyed out. So I check my access token, which returns null:

```
NSString *fbAccessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;
NSLog(@"fbAccessToken %@", fbAccessToken);
```

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950937/fbsdkaccesstoken-currentaccesstoken-nil-after-quitting-app), I need to call this first (I have implemented it inside my AppDelegate's `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`:

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                          didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions]
```

However, it returns NO, and according to FB's doc:

> @abstract  Call this method from the [UIApplicationDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] method  of the AppDelegate
>   for your app. It should be invoked for the proper use of the Facebook
>   SDK.
>
> @return YES if the url was intended for the Facebook SDK, NO if not.

I wonder why it returns NO that, perhaps, results my accessToken to be nil. Anyone can give me advise?

**UPDATE**:

I have logged-in, gained the token, allowed the permissions from my logged-in FB account, but the button is still greyed out.

Comment: Did u got the answer??

Answer (score 0):

For Android people need the native Facebook for Android app installed, version 7.0 or higher

Maybe it's the same thing on iOS.