# Bypass facebook loginview after user is logged in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I would like to know what is the best way to bypass the login viewcontroller if the user is logged in already. I have integrated Facebook in my app. I tried to check for the `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken` if it is nil or not in the appdelegate class so the app could start either from the loginviewcontroller or not, but it is not working. This is what I tried so far.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    if ((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil) {
        print("it is logged in")
    }else{
        print("it is not ")
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FBSDKLoginButton.classForCoder()



    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}
```

Either the user is logged in or not I get the same message.
What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check if the user is logged in device facebook app. You can only check if there is a valid access token or not. If there is one, you don't have to prompt user to login again.Because if accessToken is valid, you can get the user info . Again the currentAccessToken has nothing to do whether you are logged in your phone/computer facebook app or not.

You should always depend on the currentAccessToken.

```
if ((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil) {
        print("user is logged in")
    }else{
        print("user is not ")
    }
```

If the current access token is nil which is expected by default, you need to initiate the login flow through your app. Please refer to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/). Once you have finished the login flow and come back to the app, you will then have a valid access token.

In your case, the access token is nil because you are calling it before the `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` properly set.

You should do the access token check only after the call to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is finished. This reason explained in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950937/fbsdkaccesstoken-currentaccesstoken-nil-after-quitting-app)

Comment: Then how can I check if a user is logged in? By checking if there is an access token?

Comment: yes. you should always check if there is a valid access token or not.

Comment: That is exactly what I did in my AppDelegate file. But it is not working. Even if the user is logged in or logged out I get the same message.

Comment: You should explain what is not working. You will get the valid acces token, only if you initiate the login flow through your app.

Comment: When I tap the login button I normally log in with my facebook data and successfully I get back the response from facebook in my "LoginViewController". At this "LoginViewController I use the code that is mentioned for FBSDKAccessToken and it is properly working. But when I try to do the same thing in the Appdelegate file I get nothing. For example if I close the app and open it again without log out I should get the message print("user is logged in"). But I always get the other, even if I am logged in or out

Comment: It is because you are calling it at very beginning. You should only call it after the FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions) is called.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:**
I don't know how to solve the issue in your code, but there is another way of doing this, which I consider better!

---

### ***LOGIN:***

### SWIFT 2:

You can add this code to the function that does things if the user login attempt was successful:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setValue("loggedin", forKey: "yourKey")
```

---

And then, in **AppDelegate.swift** add this code, inside `ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if defaults.valueForKey("yourKey") != nil{
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController!
}
```

### ***LOGOUT:***

In the logout function, add this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setValue("loggedout", forKey: "yourKey")
```

And change the `if-statement` in `didFinishLaunching...` to this:

```
  if defaults.valueForKey("yourKey") != nil{

        let vc = UIViewController()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
        let value = defaults.valueForKey("yourKey") as! String!
    if value == "loggedin"{
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController!
    }
    else if value == "loggedout"{
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as! UIViewController!
    }
        self.window.rootViewController = viewController!

}
```

***Hope This Helps!***

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, it helps a lot. But, is this a proper/secure way to solve it?

Comment: This is not a proper way to do it, if the acces token is expired, then based on this solution, it still says that user is logged in!!

Comment: What could be a more proper way to do it? @TejaNandamuri Thank you

Comment: @user3882720 I think there is another way to properly do this, but unfortunately I cannot tell it to you, because I don't know how! I leave this job to more experienced programmers... Still, you're welcome!

Comment: @user3882720 and also I've got a question! Does your app provide logout, 'cause if so, I really need to update my answer!...

Comment: Yes I provide a logout button. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by moving the following code

```
if ((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil) {
    print("user is logged in")
}else{
    print("user is not ")
}
```

to my

```
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {}
```

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Great self-answer! And it solves the issue with the access time-out!